# Does anyone know how to make an image appear and then dissapear?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to delay the appearance of an image by about 5 mins, and then once it appears I want it to disappear after 10 seconds.

I've been able to delay the appearance of an image using the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showBuyLink() {
      document.getElementById("buylink").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    // adjust this as needed, 1 sec = 1000
    setTimeout("showBuyLink()", 300000); 
</script>
```

But then i'm unable to make it disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one may helps to you

```
   function showBuyLink() { 
      document.getElementById("buylink").style.display = "block"; 
      setTimeout(function (){
          document.getElementById("buylink").style.display = "none";
      }, 10000);    
  } 
  // adjust this as needed, 1 sec = 1000 
  setTimeout(showBuyLink(), 300000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set another timer in the show function that points to a hide function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showBuyLink() {
        document.getElementById("buylink").style.visibility = "visible"; 
        setTimeout("hideBuyLink()", 10000); 
    } 
    function hideBuyLink() {
        document.getElementById("buylink").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    } 
    // adjust this as needed, 1 sec = 1000 
    setTimeout("showBuyLink()", 300000); 
</script>
```

Alternetively, if you want it in one function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showBuyLink(){
        var buyLink = document.getElementById("buylink");
        if(buyLink.style.visibility == "hidden"){
            buyLink.style.visibility = "visible";
            setTimeout("showBuyLink()", 10000); 
        }else{
            buyLink.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
        }
    }
    // adjust this as needed, 1 sec = 1000 
    setTimeout("showBuyLink()", 300000); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually in your own code: `setTimeout(…)` is used to call a function after some time, so you can just create a second function (i.e. "hideBuyLink") and put another call to setTimeout into `showBuyLink()`.

However, it looks as if you tried to put JavaScript onto a real site on which one shall be able to buy stuff.  I advise you to contact someone to help you with the coding, since this is a beginners question, and I am afraid that you might make mistakes which could eventually be exploited by someone malicious.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("buylink").style.visibility = "visible"; 
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("buylink").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    }, 10000);
},300000);
```